# Add bash command to CMake test

Tags: c++, bash, makefile, cmake, ctest

I recently found out about CMake testing possibilities. I wrote several test-clients using it, they work ok, but to perform tests I need to:

cmake .. -> make -> then run my program in the background or other terminal -> make test (which runs all test clients/test scenarios)

Lets say I want the command: **make test** not only to run the tests, but also to run the executable(That is being tested) in background and kill it after tests complete. How can I pass a bash command via CMakeLists? I haven't found a straightforward way to achieve what I want yet

Answer (score 2):

You can do so by using `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND`. ([CMake `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command))

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to run a process in the background from ctest.   To handle this for projects like paraview that use MPI, we write a c driver program that launches the processes and performs the test/tests.   Basically each ctest test needs to be something that runs and returns a value.  However, there is of course nothing keeping that test from starting and stopping as many processes as possible.